# Synology iSCSI not mounting after repair

Tags: mount, ubuntu-10.04, open-iscsi

We have a Synology NAS device which provides iSCSI services to a large disk array. We had a couple of drives replaced and it took long for the "Repairing..." to finish and now our Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS server is not mounting the storage. When I start the open-iscsi service, the /dev/sda device gets created and has no partitions when it used to mount as /dev/sda1. If I try to mount manually:

```
# iscsi in /etc/fstab
UUID=82d94989-fabc-49f6-a9ef-e0bd9bc218c3       /srv/samba/video        ext4    defaults,auto,_netdev,acl 0 0

robert@news-storage:/etc/iscsi$ sudo mount /srv/samba/video
mount: special device UUID=82d94989-fabc-49f6-a9ef-e0bd9bc218c3 does not exist
```

The Synology GUI shows space usage of 7TB, here is my config for the node:

```
robert@news-storage:/etc/iscsi$ sudo cat nodes/iqn.2000-01.com.synology:synology.name2/192.168.1.47,3260,0/default# BEGIN RECORD 2.0-871
node.name = iqn.2000-01.com.synology:synology.name2
node.tpgt = 0
node.startup = automatic
iface.iscsi_ifacename = default
iface.transport_name = tcp
node.discovery_address = 192.168.1.47
node.discovery_port = 3260
node.discovery_type = send_targets
node.session.initial_cmdsn = 0
node.session.initial_login_retry_max = 8
node.session.xmit_thread_priority = -20
node.session.cmds_max = 128
node.session.queue_depth = 32
node.session.auth.authmethod = None
node.session.timeo.replacement_timeout = 120
node.session.err_timeo.abort_timeout = 15
node.session.err_timeo.lu_reset_timeout = 20
node.session.err_timeo.host_reset_timeout = 60
node.session.iscsi.FastAbort = Yes
node.session.iscsi.InitialR2T = No
node.session.iscsi.ImmediateData = Yes
node.session.iscsi.FirstBurstLength = 262144
node.session.iscsi.MaxBurstLength = 16776192
node.session.iscsi.DefaultTime2Retain = 0
node.session.iscsi.DefaultTime2Wait = 2
node.session.iscsi.MaxConnections = 1
node.session.iscsi.MaxOutstandingR2T = 1
node.session.iscsi.ERL = 0
node.conn[0].address = 192.168.1.47
node.conn[0].port = 3260
node.conn[0].startup = manual
node.conn[0].tcp.window_size = 524288
node.conn[0].tcp.type_of_service = 0
node.conn[0].timeo.logout_timeout = 15
node.conn[0].timeo.login_timeout = 15
node.conn[0].timeo.auth_timeout = 45
node.conn[0].timeo.noop_out_interval = 5
node.conn[0].timeo.noop_out_timeout = 5
node.conn[0].iscsi.MaxRecvDataSegmentLength = 262144
node.conn[0].iscsi.HeaderDigest = None
node.conn[0].iscsi.DataDigest = None
node.conn[0].iscsi.IFMarker = No
node.conn[0].iscsi.OFMarker = No
# END RECORD
```

I am completely new to iscsi, I have verified the target in Synology. It does connect and create the device on the local system, but no partition. Is there something else needed?